# EF 6 + DevArt Mysql connector + MONO

Tags: mysql, mono, devart

It is my first expirience to deploy .net on debian. My app was created and test in win 7 vs2012 using Devart mysql connector by using database first method, after that i was started to deploy it on linux. I met a BUNCH of obstacles!! I am out of my nerves... can anyone help ? Before that i was thinking to buy devart mysql connector prof edition... Here is my stack

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource.
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.LoadResources (System.String assemblyName, System.String resourceName, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource..ctor (System.String originalPath, System.String assemblyName, System.String resourceName, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.CreateResourceLoader (System.String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, System.String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader.Create (System.String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, System.String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader.Create (System.String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, System.String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.SplitPaths (System.String paths) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2+<>c__DisplayClass2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader]].<Evaluate>b__0 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2+Result[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader]].GetValue () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader]].Evaluate (System.String arg) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetArtifactLoader (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.DbConnectionOptions effectiveConnectionOptions) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetMetadataWorkspace (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.DbConnectionOptions effectiveConnectionOptions) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.RetrieveMetadataWorkspaceFromConnection () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor, System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory objectQueryExecutionPlanFactory, System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator translator, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor (System.String connectionString) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor (System.String connectionString, System.String defaultContainerName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at PararuLibrary.Databases.Mysql.PararuRuMysqlEntities..ctor () [0x00000] in /home/dotnetprojects/WebService1/PararuLibrary/Databases/Mysql/PararyEDM.Designer.cs:52
at PararuLibrary.Repositories.UserRepository..ctor () [0x00000] in /home/dotnetprojects/WebService1/PararuLibrary/Repositories/UserRepository.cs:24
at ConsoleTest.Program.Proceed () [0x00040] in /home/dotnetprojects/WebService1/ConsoleTest/Program.cs:28
at ConsoleTest.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /home/dotnetprojects/WebService1/ConsoleTest/Program.cs:22
```

After that i applied changes in App.config in connection string from:

```
<add name="PararuRuEntitiesCS" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Databases.Mysql.PararyEDM.csdl|res://*/Databases.Mysql.PararyEDM.ssdl|res://*/Databases.Mysql.PararyEDM.msl;provider=Devart.Data.MySql;provider connection string=&quot;User Id=root;Host=localhost;Database=pararu_ru;Persist Security Info=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

to...

```
<add name="PararuRuEntitiesCS" connectionString="metadata=res://PararuLibrary/Databases.Mysql.PararyEDM.csdl|res://PararuLibrary/Databases.Mysql.PararyEDM.ssdl|res://PararuLibrary/Databases.Mysql.PararyEDM.msl;provider=Devart.Data.MySql;provider connection string=&quot;User Id=root;Host=localhost;Database=pararu_ru;Persist Security Info=True&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

... i have this ...

```
System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
  at System.Reflection.AssemblyName.ReferenceMatchesDefinition (System.Reflection.AssemblyName reference, System.Reflection.AssemblyName definition) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.DefaultAssemblyResolver.ResolveAssembly (System.Reflection.AssemblyName referenceName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.DefaultAssemblyResolver.TryResolveAssemblyReference (System.Reflection.AssemblyName refernceName, System.Reflection.Assembly& assembly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.ResolveAssemblyName (System.String assemblyName, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.CreateResourceLoader (System.String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, System.String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader.Create (System.String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, System.String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader.Create (System.String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, System.String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.SplitPaths (System.String paths) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2+<>c__DisplayClass2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader]].<Evaluate>b__0 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2+Result[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader]].GetValue () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader]].Evaluate (System.String arg) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetArtifactLoader (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.DbConnectionOptions effectiveConnectionOptions) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetMetadataWorkspace (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.DbConnectionOptions effectiveConnectionOptions) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.RetrieveMetadataWorkspaceFromConnection () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor, System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory objectQueryExecutionPlanFactory, System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator translator, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor (System.String connectionString) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor (System.String connectionString, System.String defaultContainerName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at PararuLibrary.Databases.Mysql.PararuRuMysqlEntities..ctor () [0x00000] in /home/dotnetprojects/WebService1/PararuLibrary/Databases/Mysql/PararyEDM.Designer.cs:52
  at PararuLibrary.Repositories.UserRepository..ctor () [0x00000] in /home/dotnetprojects/WebService1/PararuLibrary/Repositories/UserRepository.cs:24
  at ConsoleTest.Program.Proceed () [0x00040] in /home/dotnetprojects/WebService1/ConsoleTest/Program.cs:28
  at ConsoleTest.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /home/dotnetprojects/WebService1/ConsoleTest/Program.cs:22
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a Mono bug. Try the following workaround: change the "Metadata Artifact Processing" model property value from "Embed In Output Assembly" to "Copy To Output Directory". Save the model, rebuild the project on Windows to make sure it works, and deploy on Mono.

Answer (score -1):

The error is clear: that method is not implemented in Mono.

Mono is an open source project. Without the contributions of people like you, it cannot keep evolving. Please consider contributing an implementation to the method (don't look at MS sources, as it would not be valid).